# probability of picking out a $1$-colored ball before a $2$-colored ball from $N_1+N_2+N_3$ balls

Tags: probability

There is an urn with $N_i$ balls of the color $i$ for $i=1,2,3$

We pick out balls one by one without putting them back.

What is the probability getting a $1$-ball before a $2$-ball?

I found $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{N_1+N_3}\frac{{(N_1+N_3)!\over (N_1+N_3-r)!}}{{(N_1+N_2+N_3)!\over (N_1+N_2+N_3-r)!}}\cdot\frac{N_2}{N_1+N_2+N_3-r}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{N_1+N_3}
\frac{(N_1+N_3)!\cdot (N_1+N_2+N_3-r)!}{(N_1+N_3-r)!\cdot (N_1+N_2+N_3)!}\cdot\frac{N_2}{N_1+N_2+N_3-r}$

It's basically the sum of the probabilities to get a sequence which contains only $1$'s and $3$'s $(r-1)$ times and the $r$-th ball is a $2$.

Would this make any sense? I feel like there is a better way

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on lulu's first paragraph:

Suppose $1$ is red, $2$ is green, and I am red-green colour-blind. So I pick out balls until I get a red/green ball. Then I show the ball to you, and you tell me what colour it is.

It should be obvious that the ball is red with probability $\dfrac{N_\text{red}}{N_\text{red}+N_\text{green}}$.

(And the argument is unchanged if we put the balls back in the urn after picking them.)

Answer (score 1):

The third color doesn't matter, so ignore it.  There are only $N_1+N_2$ "significant" draws, and $N_1$ of those are attached to the first color, so the answer is $$\frac {N_1}{N_1+N_2}$$

If you are uncomfortable ignoring the third color, you can reason by induction on $N_3$.  If $N_3=0$ the claim is clear.  Suppose we know the claim for $N_3-1$.  Then, assuming we had $N_3$ of the third color, we consider the first draw.  We see that the answer is $$\frac {N_1}{N_1+N_2+N_3}\times 1+\frac {N_2}{N_1+N_2+N_3}\times 0+\frac {N_3}{N_1+N_2+N_3}\times \frac {N_1}{N_1+N_2}$$ where we have used the inductive hypothesis to handle the third term.  Simple algebra shows that this is equal to $\frac {N_1}{N_1+N_2}$ and we are done.